# Matching data between columns only once

Tags: python

Recently, I've had the need to write several programs that utilize a similar algorithm.

Here's what I want to do:

For a spreadsheet that has multiple columns (i.e. 10), I want to compare information between cells in two particular columns and only append info. from two particular cells when there is a match according to my set criteria.

I have attempted this using nested if-statements to set my criteria, but the problem with it is that this method doesn't account for repeated cross-references.

For example, let's say I have two columns:
`Column A (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)` and
`Column B (X, Y, Z, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7)`

Then when the loops are running on the nested if-statements, it will match the `number 4` in `column A` with the `number 4` in `column B` once (which would be correct), but then it would match the `number 3` in `column A` with both `number 3`'s in `column B`, which I don't want.

Pretty much what I'm trying to say is, once the program finds a match for a particular set of cells within the loop, I want it to exclude them from consideration when the loop continues.

Any idea on how to accomplish something like this?

Comment: Can you provide some code that you tried?

Comment: And what do you expect at the end of that code?

Comment: @PetrJoachim At the end of the code, for each match, I want to append a certain set of values from a bunch of columns on the spreadsheet that correspond to that match.

Comment: @bioprogrammer this is so confusing. So you are picking each line where value in ColA doesn't exists as a value in any line in ColB?

Answer (score 2):

You can try it with set arithmetics. Look for docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset

```
frozenset(('a', 'b', 'c', 4)) - frozenset((4, 5))
>> frozenset(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `break` statement. So, something like this:

```
for x in first_cell:
    for y in second_cell:
       if x == y:
           # Found match -- do something
           break
```

The `break` statement jumps out of the inner loop. So you stop checking items in the second cell once you find a match. It would continue with the outer loop (so, check the next item in the first cell).